# How to Check or detect if Window is minimized or not active in SDL?

Tags: events, window, sdl, sdl-2

I want to do some background work if window is minimized or not active but how can I detect if the window is active or not in SDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SDL_GetWindowFlags()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowFlags) & check for the `SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED`/`SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_FOCUS`/`SDL_WINDOW_MOUSE_FOCUS` flags.